# Drag multiple items inside another item in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have three circles in a rectangle. Whenever I drag the rectangle all three circles should move with my rectangle. However, whenever I move one of the circles that specific circle should move. Other circles and rectangle should not move.

[image]

I have no idea where should I start from. I know how to drag a single circle or multiple circles but no idea how to do this. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```js
var w = 200, h = 200;
var drag = d3.behavior.drag().on('dragstart',function(){
  d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
}).on("drag", function() {       
    var x = d3.event.x,
    y = d3.event.y;
    if(this.tagName=='circle'){
      if(x<=w-10 && x>=10 && y<=h-10 && y>=10)
      d3.select(this).attr("cx",x).attr("cy",y);
    }else
      d3.select(this).attr("transform","translate("+x+","+y+")");
});;
var container = d3.select('body').append("svg").attr("width",1200).attr("height",600);
var group = container.append("g")
var rect = group.append("rect").attr("width",w).attr("height",h).attr("x",10).attr("yx",10);
var circle1 = group.append("circle").attr("cx",50).attr("cy",50).attr("r",10).style("fill","red");
var circle2 = group.append("circle").attr("cx",100).attr("cy",70).attr("r",10).style("fill","red");
circle1.call(drag);
circle2.call(drag);
group.call(drag);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```